# How to create Complex IF Condition in MySQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, database-trigger

I have situation with my trigger here. My IF statement is not working properly. I am stuck and have spent many hours trying to troubleshoot it.

This is my code :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`administrator`@`%` TRIGGER `My_Trigger` AFTER INSERT ON `my_first_table` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE A FLOAT default 0;
SET A = NEW.Data;

IF (A < 60.00 && NEW.Node <> 'XXX') OR (A < 60.00 && NEW.Node <> 'YYY') OR (A < 60.00 && NEW.Node <> 'ZZZ')
  THEN
    INSERT INTO `my_database`.`my_table` VALUES ('Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', NEW.Node, A);
  END IF;
END
```

So, If I only using one Node (not using **OR** in if statement), the trigger working perfectly.

The question is, How to make IF statement with a lot of **OR**?

Thanks

Comment: What's the exact error message, and the exact statement you're trying to execute?

Comment: In what way is it not working when you add multiple `OR` clauses?

Comment: @Nick The if statement not working, data with Node Value XXX, YYY, and ZZZ inserted to my_table. I only want to Insert when A below 60, and the node is not XXX, YYY, and ZZZ

Comment: Ah then your logic is incorrect, you should be using `AND`, not `OR`, you can simplify it to `A < 60.00 AND NEW.Node <> 'XXX' AND NEW.Node <> 'YYY AND NEW.Node <> 'ZZZ'`

Comment: Topicstarter and @Nick notice the `AFTER INSERT ON `my_table` and `INSERT INTO `my_database`.`my_table` in the code this is not possible, it seams he is trying to insert into the same table where the trigger is running on.. This is offcource not possible because off a infinite loop..

Comment: @RaymondNijland OP has just edited the question to change the trigger table name

Comment: @RaymondNijland Sorry I already edit my trigger, please check the new one. My bad

Comment: @MohamadNajib did you try my suggestion?

Comment: @Nick Not yet. I want to try it. I'll let you know if it work. Thank you

Comment: No problem Topicstarter  and @Nick i call them as i see them if something does not make sense syntax wise you will hear it from me

Comment: @RaymondNijland absolutely. I was just posting a comment saying that if it did work at all the two tables must be different (I was positing that perhaps they were in different databases) when the edit came in.

Comment: indeed @Nick the other database thoery also might have been possible, triggers can work across databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to Insert when A is below 60, and the node is not XXX, YYY, and ZZZ, you need to use `AND` logic instead. Try this:

```
IF (A < 60.00 AND NEW.Node <> 'XXX' AND NEW.Node <> 'YYY' AND NEW.Node <> 'ZZZ')
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your correction, It's work now. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `||` instead of `OR` or try encapsulating the three conditions.
Try if the example below works for you.

```
IF (A < 60.00 AND (NEW.Node <> 'XXX' OR NEW.Node <> 'YYY' OR NEW.Node <> 'ZZZ'))
  THEN
    INSERT INTO `my_database`.`my_table` VALUES ('Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', NEW.Node, A);
  END IF;
END
```

Comment: `OR` and `||` are one and the same in MySQL.

Comment: True, but it makes no sense to me to use `&&` and then `OR` mixed in a condition.

Comment: That is a valid point, but it does not offer a solution to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want `NOT IN`:

```
IF (A < 60.00 AND NEW.Node NOT IN ('XXX', 'YYY', 'ZZZ')) THEN
    INSERT INTO `my_database`.`my_table`
        VALUES ('Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', NEW.Node, A);
END IF;
```

I also strongly encourage you to use `AND` and `OR` -- which are the standard boolean operators in SQL -- and not `||` and `&&` which are MySQL extensions.